# \printbibliography is always blank (warnings given)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, miktex, biber

I cannot get a bibliography working using biblatex. Even the most basic example doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{refs.bib} 

\begin{document} 

Hello \cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

As far as I can understand, I run the following commands on the file (test1.tex):

```
pdflatex test1        (This gets some warnings, but ignore)
biber test1
pdflatex test1
```

biber gives a warning:

```
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 2.3
```

The second pdflatex command gives warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'KandR' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 21.
LaTex Warning: There were undefined references.
```

I have tried several things already:

- Using the bibtex command gives:

  ```
  The top-level auxiliary file: test1.aux
  I found no \citation commands---while reading file test1.aux
  I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test1.aux
  I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test1.aux
  ```
- Using [backend=biber] doesn't change anything

Some notes:

- Windows 8
- MikTex 2.9
- TeXworks
  -

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you launch `latex` then `bibtex` (or `biber`) and then `latex` again?

Comment: You are confusing `bibtex` and `biber` either in your usage or in your description here.  `backend=biber` means you need biber, but then you say you use the 'bibtex command'..?  It also sounds like you have mismatched versions of `biblatex` and `biber`, the development of which are closely coupled.  Make sure your versions match.  There is a table (early on) in the `biblatex` manual that documents which versions work together.

Comment: the only error you are supposed to have, at least when I compiled it, is `did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?` which it's specified in `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` or `bibtex` if you'd rather have it instead. And you should omit the `bib` extension, since `\addbibresource{refs.bib}` is specified in the document so `\begin{filecontents*}{refs}`

Comment: The `biber` warning tells you that your version of `biber` is out of sync with your version of `biblatex`.  You should first update.

Comment: Did updating `biber` and `biblatex` solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I try this code with `biber` backend. For compiling I use `xelatex` and *UTF format* for all files:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backref=true,                % 
            hyperref=true,               % 
            firstinits=true,             %
            indexing=true,               %
            url=false,                   % 
            style=alphabetic,            %  style=debug, alphabetic
            backend=biber,               % 
            doi=false,
            texencoding=utf8,
            bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Your name},
            pdftitle={Your article},
            pdfsubject={My study notes},
            pdfkeywords={linear algebra, math, physics, electronics},
            pdfpagelayout={TwoPageLeft}, % Displays two pages, odd-numbered pages to the left 
            pdfcreator={Xelatex}
            bookmarks={true},            %  A set of Acrobat bookmarks are written
            colorlinks={true},           %  Colors the text of links and anchors. 
            anchorcolor={black},         %  Color for anchor text.
            filecolor={cyan},            %  Color for URLs which open local files.
            menucolor={red},             %  Color for Acrobat menu items.
            runcolor={blue}              %  Color for run links (launch annotations).        
           }           
\addbibresource{refs.bib}    
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{refs.bib} 

\begin{document} 

Hello \cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

Please check if the file with extension **bbl** exists and has nonzero size. In case, that this file has zero size or not exist try to create it manually. Use command line and type this:

```
biber yourexample.bcf
```

Comment: Why do you add ```\addbibresource{refs.bib} ``` twice and you ```\usepackage{biblatex}``` twice?

Comment: @AndreaAraldo: Thanks. It is a bug.